# Can't save more than one string using Json

Tags: java, json

I have a problem. I've been doing a simple REST app project and now I need to send JSON from http client for creating an entity. When I sent one property it's ok, but when I write another one it stores the second property to the same string. 
It looks like this(the actual entity is in the list "toDos"):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "block2",
    "archive": null,
    "toDos": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "{\n  \"text\" : \"my third todo\",\n  \"scaryness\" : 1,\n  \"hardness\" : 1\n}",
            "scaryness": null,
            "hardness": null,
            "ready": false,
            "createdOn": "2018-11-10T19:19:23.32207"
        }
    ]
}
```

My POST request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/todos/create-todo/1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "text" : "my third todo",
  "scaryness" : 1,
  "hardness" : 1
}
```

My project on github: https://github.com/FedosovMax/to-do-app

Help me please to find out how do send scaryness and hardness to the right places. If additional information needed, write me please.

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake in the RestController, my code was next:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create-todo/{blockId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createToDo(@PathVariable long blockId, @RequestBody String text, Scaryness scaryness, Hardness hardness){
    toDoService.saveToDo(text, scaryness, hardness, blockId);
}
```

So it saved as one String. Now my RestController looks like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create-todo/{blockId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createToDo(@PathVariable long blockId, @RequestBody ToDo toDo){
    toDoService.saveToDo(toDo, blockId);
}
```

and it works right.

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "block2",
    "archive": null,
    "toDos": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "my third todo",
            "scaryness": 1,
            "hardness": 2,
            "ready": false,
            "createdOn": null
        }
```